# Live iOS App Crashing at Startup

Tags: ios

I have had an iOS app in the app store since October 2015. Today I noticed that the app is crashing upon startup. The load screen will appear, but then the app will crash. I tested the behavior on two different devices and I have noticed that it crashes on other devices that previously installed the app.

Here are some notes about the app:

- I haven't made any updates or resubmissions
- Previously worked fine without any problems
- I noticed that my development certificate was revoked when a developer was working in my account.

  - The provisioning profile somehow became invalid after one of my certificates was revoked.

Any reason why my app would suddenly start crashing?

**Update**

I pulled the crashlog from my phone and uploaded the file. Here is the link:

[Link to crashlog](http://www.filedropper.com/crashlog)

Comment: Check the crash logs, you might find out some clues about why the application is crashing.

Comment: Are the crashes coming from an app installed from the App Store or installed through Xcode or some other non-App Store method?

Comment: The crashes are coming from an app that is installed in the App Store. The app has been in the app store for months and it suddenly started crashing.

Comment: My bet is that you are crashing on an OS version that was released after your app was released. I suggest testing it on older iOS versions and move forward, testing each major release up to 9.2 until you find the problem.

Comment: @DuncanC thanks for the response. That's what I thought. My iPhone is using iOS 9.2 and the app worked find in iOS 9.2 until yesterday. So I'm not sure if that is the problem.

Comment: @socialedu You didn't answer my question. I know your app is in the App Store. I'm asking how the crashing app was installed. Was it installed from the App Store or was it installed from some other means such as Xcode or iTunes?

Comment: @rmaddy sorry, I think that I originally misunderstood your question. The crashing app was installed from the App Store on my phone. Also, I found another person with an iPhone and installed the app from the App store onto their phone and the app also crashed. This app has had about 577 installs and only 5 crashes prior to it crashing on me for the first time yesterday.

Comment: OK, just wanted to verify that it is an App Store install that is crashing. You need get the crash log and see why and where it is crashing.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks! I didn't know that I could do that. I just pulled the crash log and I have no idea what I'm looking at. I posted the link to the log back in the document. It looks like it might have something to do with memory but I'm not sure.